# how to add two php variables in one database column while using prepare statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement, sql-injection

**Iam using this for simple query**

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $Seats; $i++)
    {
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table3(Id,Type,name,rows)VALUES('".$Id."','".$Type."','".$Name."','".$Name."".$i."')");
}
```

> How can i insert last two variables in database with prepare statement
>   like i do in simple query

**iam using prepare statement here**

```
$insert="INSERT INTO table3(Id,Type,name,rows)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($insert);
```

**how can i pas variables here**

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $Id,$Type,$Name, $Name $i);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Just make a variable by adding those two variables before executing bind_param and use that variable in 4th parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$insert="INSERT INTO table3(Id,Type,name,rows)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($insert);
$lastParam = $name.$i;
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $Id,$Type,$Name, $lastParam);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try adding a dot (concatenation) for you last param :

```
$row = $Name . $i;
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $Id, $Type, $Name, $row);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Edit**

But please note the fact to store the variable "$name" in two different columns is a bad practice. You should just store "$i" in the column that you named "rows" and manually concatenate "name" and "rows" when retrieving the results.
It will simplify :

- the update of the "name" if you want to change it for some reason : only one column to update, instead of two
- if you want to change $name . $id by $name . "-" . $id, you will not have to update your entire DB.

Comment: Showing this error sir..Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 5 by reference

Comment: ok, so try to use a temporary variable before : 
`$row= $name.$id;` and then use '$row' in the binding